# How to properly add fields to models with South?

Tags: django, django-south

I have a django app called `Locations` and in its `models.py` there are 2 models:

```
class City(models.Model):
 ...

class Country(models.Model):
 ...
```

I did python `manage.py schemamigration Locations --initial` and then `python manage.py migrate Locations`. Everything worked fine.

Then I added 2 fields to `City` and did `python manage.py schemamigration Locations --auto` and it said:

- Deleted field cover_image on Locations.Country
- Added field lng on Locations.City
- Added field ltd on Locations.City
  Created 0003_auto__del_field_country_cover_image__add_field_city_lng__add_field_cit.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate Locations

Then when I did `python manage.py migrate Locations`, I got:

```
Running migrations for Locations:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__del_field_country_cover_image__add_field_city_lng__add_field_cit.
 > Locations:0001_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "Locations_country" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, "slug" varchar(50) NOT NULL, "image" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "flag" varchar(100) NOT NULL)
The error was: relation "Locations_country" already exists

Error in migration: Locations:0001_initial
DatabaseError: relation "Locations_country" already exists
```

I always keep getting this error. Am I doing something wrong?

Then I did `python manage.py migrate Locations 0003 --fake` and this was the output:

```
- Soft matched migration 0003 to 0003_auto__del_field_country_cover_image__add_field_city_lng__add_field_cit.
Running migrations for Locations:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__del_field_country_cover_image__add_field_city_lng__add_field_cit.
 > Locations:0001_initial
   (faked)
 > Locations:0002_auto__add_field_city_lng__add_field_city_ltd
   (faked)
 > Locations:0002_auto__add_location__add_field_country_cover_image
   (faked)
 > Locations:0003_auto__del_field_country_cover_image__add_field_city_lng__add_field_cit
   (faked)
```

Now when I do `python manage.py migrate Locations` it says:

```
Running migrations for Locations:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for Locations.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

And those 2 fields have not been added. Whats going on? Whats the correct way to add/delete fields?

I have read the basic South documentation, please point to me if I have missed out something.

Thanks.

Comment: Somehow the table got created before you ran South. Did you run `syncdb`? Try rolling back to 0002, dropping the `Locations_country` table manually from your DB, and running the migration in South.

Comment: Yes I might have run syncdb. How do I roll back to 0002? And I cannot drop Locations_country because I have data in it. What should I do?

Comment: You converted the app to south after syncing the tables?

Comment: @AamirAdnan No but I must have done `syncdb --all` after migrating.

Comment: So syncdb -all force all tables to sync regardless of south managing it. Now you have faked all migrations so there is no problem now. Because syncdb --all has already added new fields so there is no now no need for south to done that again.

Comment: You should avoid `syncdb --all` unless it is necessary, just use `syncdb` in future.

Comment: Ok...No, the fields have not been added. I dont understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41373/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-h-h-h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `0002` and `0003` migrations files. And then roll back to `0001` by doing:

```
python manage.py migrate Locations 0001 --fake --delete-ghost-migrations
```

After that run `schemamigration` and `migrate` normally.

(During discussion with OP it was first cleared that `0002` and `0003` was never reflected to database, so it is no harm to delete those migration files from disk)